# Thymeleaf aggregation not working

Tags: thymeleaf, aggregation, spring-el

We've got the following code:

```
<div th:each="client : ${clients}">
    <div th:each="purchase : ${client.purchases}">
        <div th:each="product : ${purchase.products}">
            <span th:text="${product.price}"></span>
            <!-- <span id="2" th:text="${#aggregates.sum(products.{price})}"> </span> -->
            <!-- <span id="2" th:text="${#aggregates.sum(products.![price])}"> </span>  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output is:

```
5.25
4.20
```

If I uncomment the first comment, I get error

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#aggregates.sum(products.{price})" (clients/clients:84)
```

If I uncomment only the second comment, I get error:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#aggregates.sum(products.![price])" (clients/clients:85)
```

I tried to use http://demo-dspace-cris.cineca.it/bitstream/123456789/26/1/usingthymeleaf.pdf

I am using `thymeleaf 2.1.4`

**IT WORKS !**

I should use:

```
<span id="2" th:text="${#aggregates.sum(purchase.products.![price])}"> </span>
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it myself after posting here !

```
<div th:each="client : ${clients}">

            <div th:each="purchase : ${client.purchases}">
                <span id="2"
                    th:text="${#aggregates.sum(purchase.products.![price])}"> </span>
                <div th:each="product : ${purchase.products}">
                    <span th:text="${product.price}"></span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

output:

```
9.45
5.25
4.20
```

site that helped me a lot: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/aggregates-with-Spring-td3767446.html